# Why Dengue is considered an Epidemic and not a Pandemic?

Tags: epidemiology, pandemic, dengue

According to [Pandemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandemic) (and many other sources with similar definitions) a Pandemic is

> an epidemic of disease that has spread across a large region, for
>   instance multiple continents or worldwide, affecting a substantial
>   number of people

And according to [Dengue fever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dengue_fever)

Dengue has become a global problem since the Second World War and is common in more than 120 countries, mainly in Asia and South America. (Note: it also exists in North America, Oceania and Africa) About 390 million people are infected a year and approximately 40,000 die.

However, this year we are having dozens of thousands of cases in my country and media only talks about epidemy, also, as far as I know, WHO hasnt declared a Dengue Pandemic.

My question is,

Why Dengue is considered an Epidemic and not a Pandemic?

Comment: The WHO is a political organisation. The SARS-CoV-2 outbreak also applied to this definition before the WHO decided to classify it as a pandemic. The pandemic is - apart from the epidemiological term - also a legal term with certain consequences associated with declaring an outbreak a pandemic. Also, a large region is always debatable, as well as a substantial number of people. I'm afraid that there is probably not gonna be a satisfying answer to this question.